# Need a Mysql Query to display rows as per my wish

Tags: mysql

I am working on a article posting app..

Users can post an article..the article will be inserted as a row with a unique id in the posts table..

That post should be shown only once to the other users..and it will not be shown to the user who have posted..

The viewed posts are stored in the separate table contains the post id and the viewed user number..

I use the Query..

```
SELECT Posts.NAME, Posts.TITLE, Posts.NUMBER    
FROM Posts LEFT JOIN Viewed 
ON Posts.ID = Viewed.POSTID AND Posts.NUMBER != Viewed.NUMBER
WHERE Viewed.POSTID IS NULL AND Posts.NUMBER != '".$number"'
```

This query is displaying the post only for the first viewer...not for others!

Kindly Help!

Answer (score 0):

You must use the [EXISTS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html) keyword to see if there is a View entry (or not) for a given post and user. It should look something like this:

```
SELECT
    Posts.NAME,
    Posts.TITLE,
    Posts.NUMBER
FROM
    Posts
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT
        1
    FROM
        Viewed
    WHERE
        Viewed.USERID = ? AND
        Viewed.POSTID = Posts.ID
)
```

Comment: Thank you, but why you have selected 1 in not exists?